# Auto documenting Python 3 with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am getting the following error when running sphinx:

```
"invalid syntax (DaPL.py, line 79)", please check your spelling and sys.path
```

However the file runs perfectly fine. The line is:

```
print("Warning: A value for", k, "was not specified. It will be inferred.",
    file=sys.stderr)
```

How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**:

I added another valid print line in a module that was auto-docing correctly and got the same error:

```
print('one', 'two', 'three', file=sys.stderr)
```

When I remove `file=sys.stderr`, I no longer get the error.

Comment: What options are you using for sphinx? Is there any way to make the problem reproducible?

Comment: @DavidRobinson It isn't my `sys.path` because I have other modules that are autodocumenting correctly. I'm using `autodoc`, `viewcode`, and `todo` extensions. Everything else are the quickstart defaults.

Comment: the main purpose of sphinx it's not exactly the one that you want to achieve, for what you are trying to do there is http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/ that is right for the job.

Comment: It seems like Sphinx runs with a Python 2 interpreter. See http://www.mail-archive.com/sphinx-dev@googlegroups.com/msg05203.html

Comment: @mzjn I think you're right, but I'm not sure how to force it to use python 3. I've looked at the Makefile and conf.py without success.

Comment: @clementine: if what you write under UPDATE solved the problem, I think you should submit that as an answer (and accept it) so that it is clear that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing sphinx with `easy_install` I needed to specify `easy_install3`. This made `python3` the default interpreter.

```
easy_install3 sphinx
```